# when using System.Transactions connect database connect error

Tags: .net, db2, entity, informix

i use IBM.data.server to connect informix  using Entity Framework 6

```
using (var test = new COMMONEntities())
{
   var configs = from a  in   test.SYS_CONFIG select a ;
   foreach ( var u in configs)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(u.ID);
   }

}
```

connect is ok ！
however when i use System.Transactions , it can't connect to database

```
System.Transactions.TransactionOptions transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions();
transactionOptions.IsolationLevel =IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
using (var transactionScope = new System.Transactions.
            TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions))
{
        using (var test2 = new COMMONEntities())
        { 
        var configs = from a in test2.SYS_CONFIG select a;
        foreach (var u in configs) 《== here will Exception (db2 can’t open ) 
        {
         Console.WriteLine(u.ID);
         }
        transactionScope.Complete();
}
```

Is the lack of what configuration?

Comment: DB2 or Informix? These are different things, you know.

Comment: informix  use  ibm.data.db2  , there is  error msg

Comment: Looks like you forgot to post the error message. Still, DB2 and Informix are different things. What database are you connecting to? Please only leave relevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

by default, entity Framework use transaction. Do all your add, update, remove and then use save method, that's all